# Did Euclid prove the formula for the area of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, math-history, area

In [Proposition 6.23](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI23.html) of Euclid’s Elements, Euclid proves a result which in modern language says that the area of a parallelogram is equal to base times height.  Now Euclid did not have the concept of real numbers at his disposal, so how he phrased the result is, the ratio of the area of one parallelogram to the area of another parallelogram is equal to the ratio of the bases times the ratio of their heights (where multiplication of ratios is defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1855688/71829)),

But my question is, did Euclid ever prove that the area of a triangle is 1/2 base times height?  That is, did he prove that the ratio of the area of a triangle to the area of a parallelogram is equal to one half the ratio of their bases times the ratio of their heights?

Euclid’s system is certainly capable of proving it; the result follows pretty directly from Proposition 6.23 along with [Proposition 1.41](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI41.html), which says that the area of a triangle is half the area of a parallelogram with the same base and height.  But did Euclid actually prove this result in the *Elements*?

Comment: See [Prop. I.42](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI42.html).

Comment: PROPOSITION 41.  THEOREM
If a parallelogram and a triangle are on same base and in the same parallels, the parallelogram is double the triangle.

Comment: @stevengregory I cited Proposition 1.41 in my question.  The fact that the area of a triangle is half the area of a parellogram with the same base and height does not by itself imply that the area of a triangle is half base times height.  For that you need to know that the area of a parallelogram is in fact base times height.  That is why I said the result follows from Proposition 6.23 along with Proposition 1.41.  But I want to know whether Euclid actually proved that result in the Elements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Neither of the results you cite prove that area = half base times height.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Again, the fact that tha area of a triangle is half the area of a parallelogram with the same base and height doesn’t by itself imply that the area of a triangle is half base times height.  For that you need to know that the area of a parallelogram is bass times height.

Comment: You have to take into account that figures (lines, triangles, parallelograms) are measured by *magnitudes*, and magnitudes are not *numbers* (that in Greek math are only natural ones). Thus, the "product" of two perpendicular segments produces a rectangle and **not** a number.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, I am fully taking that into account.  That is why Proposition 6.23 is about multiplying ratios of magnitudes and not about multiplying magnitudes.  It says that the ratio of the area of two parallelograms is equal to the ratio of their bases times the ratio of the heights.  So in this case what we need to prove is that that ratio of the area of a triangle to the area of a parallelogram is equal to 1/2 the ratio of their bases times the ratio of their heights.  Now as I said, it’s easy to prove using 6.23 along with 1.41, but I want to know if Euclid actually proved it.

Comment: In *Elements* there is not a def of *area* : there is the concept of [parallelogrammic areas (I.34)](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI34.html) and a technique of "cut-and-paste" to show that plane figures are equal (in modern terms : have the same area).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Euclid did determine exactly how big the area of parallelogram is, using the language of ratios.  See [proposition 6.23](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI23.html).

Comment: I think that a complete answer must be along these lines: *Elements* is a "composite" book, made of different layers with difefrent "age" and different topics: the more ancient "synthetic" theory of plane figures; the ancient Pythagorean theory of (natural) numbers; the more recent Eudoxian theory of *ratio* of magnitused.

Comment: If so, we may speculate that maybe Euclid did not consider relevant to re-prove the already stated result regarding the way to construct a rectangle with the same area of a given triangle, with the tools of the more mature theory of ratios. Maybe...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Regardless, I specifically want to know if Euclid ever proved that that the ratio of the area of a triangle to the area of a parallelogram is equal to 1/2 the ratio of the bases times the ratio of the heights.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on comments of @Mauro ALLEGRANZA regarding this interesting question, I believe Euclid does not prove the formula for the area of a triangle, nor does *Elements VI, 23* show that the area of a parallelogram is equal to base times height.

"The ratio of the area of a triangle to the area of a parallelogram is equal to one half the ratio of their bases times the ratio of their heights," and "the area of a triangle is 1/2 base times height," are not equivalent propositions, nor does the second follow from the first in light of *I, 41*, as OP seems to claim in his second paragraph and fourth and sixth comments.

When Euclid proves in *VI, 23* that the areas of equiangular parallelograms are in the ratio compounded of the ratios of their sides, he is speaking and thinking not arithmetically but geometrically. Allowing for incommensurability, he does not suppose the sides are in the ratio of a number to a number, and hence that multiplication of ratios is even possible. *Compounding* of ratios, as his proof makes clear, is a purely geometric idea and operation, working with lines and areas as continuous, unmeasured, possibly incommensurable, magnitudes.

Euclid is considering the ratio of the areas of *two* parallelograms, and he is not viewing those areas, or the sides that contain them, as subject to numerical measurement. And even where magnitudes, e.g. lengths or areas, prove to be equal, equality in the geometric parts of *Elements* is evidenced not by numerical measure but rather by spatial coincidence, either as a whole, as in *I, 4*, or when broken into parts, as in *I, 35*.

Although *I, 41* of course proves that the area of a triangle is half that of a parallelogram of the same base and height, it jars with Euclid's entire approach to say either that the area of a triangle is equal to half its base times its height, or that the area of a parallelogram is equal to base times height. It is true that he did not have the concept of real numbers at his disposal, but that is only part of the reason. For Euclid geometry is not dependent on arithmetic. In fact, geometry can go where arithmetic cannot follow. Not until the seventeenth century does Descartes (*Geometry*) boast of overcoming what he calls the "scruple" the ancients had against introducing the terms of arithmetic into geometry. But even Isaac Newton, fifty years later, prefers to formulate and prove the propositions of *Principia* as geometric proportions rather than algebraic equations. And Dedekind of course (*Continuity and Irrational Numbers*), as zealous for the independence of arithmetic as Euclid was for that of geometry, sought to provide a foundation for continuity in the domain of numbers without appealing, as was usual before him, to geometric intuition.

I think it is fair to say, that Euclid proved that the ratio of the area of a triangle to that of a parallelogram is one-half the ratio *compounded* of the ratios of their bases and heights, or, with some stretching of the term, one-half the ratio of their bases *times* the ratio of their heights. But it does not follow from this, that in Euclid's view a triangle's area *equals* half its base times its height, or that a parallelogram's area *equals* base times height. Not that these formulas are to be rejected, of course, but they do not arise from, or comport well with, the principles and point of view of *Elements*.

Comment: It is of course perfectly true that Euclid would not have thought of things in this way.  But the purpose of my question is to find out, if we, us modern people, equate real numbers with ratios, then did Euclid prove a proposition which would imply (for us) that area equals half base times height.

Comment: You say “I think it is fair to say, that Euclid proved that the ratio of the area of a triangle to that of a parallelogram is one-half the ratio compounded of the ratios of their bases and heights” What proposition does Euclid prove this in?

Comment: If I think "real number" when Euclid says "ratio", and "times" when he says "compounded", then when he says ($VI, 23$) that similar parallelograms have to one another the ratio compounded of the ratios of their sides, I will think that that the area of parallelogram $A$ has to the area of parallelogram $B$ the ratio that that product of the sides of $A$ has to the product of the sides of $B$. Or, using base and height, I will say that $A$ has to $B$ the ratio that base-times-height of $A$ has to base-times height of $B$. So far ok. But how do you go from there to say area A=base-times-height?

Comment: As for the proposition about the ratio of a triangle's area to that of a parallelogram, Euclid does not prove it. I say I think it's fair to say, but I'm not sure "half a ratio" is defined for Euclid. He speaks of duplicate and triplicate ratios, but they aren't double and triple in the usual sense. What do you think? But even granting that Euclid holds the proposition implicitly, it still seems a leap to me to go from equating the ratio of two areas with half the ratio of the product of base times height, to equating the area of a single triangle $A$ with half base-times-height.